# Css not formatting div's correctly

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I am running through a stored procedure in my code and what I want to achieve is a table that has a large image on the left of the page and then 4-5 smaller images beside it on the right. I am setting the larger image first and then running through the smaller images after that.  My problem is the alignment of the images.  The smaller images don't want to stack correctly and then the next rom of larger and smaller images are being skewed.  See code below.

Dim table1 As New HtmlTable

```
Dim numells As Integer = 6


dv = New DataView(dt1.Tables(0))
Dim tablestring = ""



Dim strTable As New StringBuilder()
Dim rowIsOpen As Boolean = False
Dim itmCounter As Integer = 0
strTable.Append("<div class=table3test>")



For Each dr As DataRowView In dv



    Dim crossover As String = dr("ID").ToString()
    Dim picid As String = dr("StyleName").ToString()
    Dim picdescrip As String = dr("StyleNumber").ToString().ToUpper()
    Dim collectionname As String = dr("Collection").ToString()
    Dim designinfo As String = dr("GroupName").ToString()
    Dim mainimage As String = dr("RoomScene").ToString

    Session("Collection") = collectionname

    If itmCounter = 0 Then
        If mainimage = "Yes" Then

            strTable.Append("" & collectionname & " Collection</br>")
            strTable.Append("<div class=celltest7><a class=hyperlink     href=""Sheet-Vinyl-Tile-Product-Page.aspx?p=" & crossover & "&o=" & designinfo & """>")
            strTable.Append("<img src=""Images/Main/" + picdescrip + " " + picid + ".jpg""width=""400"" height=""400"" border=""0"""" /><br/>")
            strTable.Append("<div class=backgroundcolor>" & picdescrip + " " + collectionname & "")
            strTable.Append("</a></div></div>")

        Else

        End If
      End If

     `enter code here`  If itmCounter <> 0 Then
            If testtable <> collectionname Then
                strTable.Append("</br></br>")
                If mainimage = "Yes" Then

                strTable.Append("" & collectionname & " Collection</br>")
                strTable.Append("<div class=celltest7><a class=hyperlink href=""Sheet-Vinyl-Tile-Product-Page.aspx?p=" & crossover & "&o=" & designinfo & """>")
                strTable.Append("<img src=""Images/Main/" + picdescrip + " " + picid + ".jpg""width=""400"" height=""400"" border=""0"""" /><br/>")
                strTable.Append("<div class=backgroundcolor>" & picdescrip + " " + collectionname & "")
                strTable.Append("</a></div></div>")

            Else

                End If

            Else


            End If
        End If






    If itmCounter Mod 3 = 0 Then

        rowIsOpen = True
    End If


    strTable.Append("<div class=celltestpublic1><div class=celltestpublic><a class=hyperlink href=""Sheet-Vinyl-Tile-Product-Page.aspx?p=" & crossover & "&o=" & designinfo & """>")
    strTable.Append("<img src=""Images/Swatches/" + picdescrip + " " + picid + ".jpg""width=""200"" height=""200"" border=""0"""" /><br/></div>")
    strTable.Append("<div class=backgroundcolor>" & picdescrip + " " + collectionname & "")
    strTable.Append("</a></div></div>")


    itmCounter += 1

    testtable = Session("Collection")

Next
strTable.Append("</div>")
product.InnerHtml = strTable.ToString()

con5.Close()
```

CSS

```
.celltest7 {
    width:   30%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border: 8px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;
}
.celltestpublic {
    width: 70%;  

}
.celltestpublic1
{
    float: left;
    width:  200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    /*margin-bottom: 15px;*/
}
.table3test
{
    width: 100%;
    }
```